# Php list to be sortet alphabetically

Tags: php, alphabetical, alphabetical-sort

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I sort this array by key with usort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915682/how-should-i-sort-this-array-by-key-with-usort)

I have tried following a lot of hints to sort a list alphabetically on this piece of code with no luck.

```
<?php
foreach ($this->link_items as &$item) :
?>
<li>
<a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($item->slug, $item->catid)); ?>">
            <?php echo $item->title; ?></a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I need this list to be sortet before its output.

Comment: *(tip)* [Do not use references](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/125-Do-not-use-PHP-references.html)

Comment: possible solution: http://codepad.viper-7.com/2KTIFv

Answer (score 0):

```
sort($this->link_items);
```

This will sort values by their value. To sort by key, use `ksort`.

Comment: the `$link_items` are objects, so this wont work. The OP needs to use `usort` and compare the item titles.

Comment: He doesn't actually mention this in his question. I worked with the information he provided. Does this really require a downvote?

Comment: It's fairly obvious from the question given that the OP first does `foreach ($this->link_items as &$item)` and then accesses `$item->title` and other properties. As for the dv, well, technically the answer is wrong, so yes, but it's more meant to encourage you to correct the question (not to punish you).

Comment: An array can be read in an object oriented method, as he has here. There is nothing saying it can't be an array he is sorting.

Comment: Occam's Razor: the most obvious explanation for two competing theories is usually the right explanation and `$item->title` hints at an object property. Besides, if the OP doesnt know how to sort a list of objects by their properties, s/he likely wont know how to use an ArrayObject (not an array) either.

Comment: Agree. But, just because somethings obvious, doesn't make it the truth. I've seen more obscure usages of arrays before. But, I see your point.

Answer (score -1):

USE:

```
$sorted_array = array_multisort($this->link_items, SORT_ASC);
<?php
foreach ($sorted_array as &$item) :
?>
<li>
<a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($item->slug, $item->catid)); ?>">
            <?php echo $item->title; ?></a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: `array_multisort` returns a boolean. even if it would return the sorted array, the result will likely be wrong because the objects have multiple properties.