# Get sorted data by key value highest of array

Tags: php

I have a variable $_SESSION["cart_item"] which stores cart items by array like given below -

```
Array
( 
    [0] => Array
        (
            [company] => ABC company 
            [good] => Laptop 
            [price] => 100 
            [ship] => 20 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [company] => ABC company 
            [good] => PC 
            [price] => 20
            [ship] => 70 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [company] => DELL PLC 
            [good] => Hard Drive 
            [price] => 500 
            [ship] => 50 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [company] => ABC company 
            [good] => Bag 
            [price] => 30
            [ship] => 40 
        )

)
```

I want to get the sorted data by company and the `[ship]` is highest value.

Comment: And you want to Sort by?......

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I sort this array by key with usort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915682/how-should-i-sort-this-array-by-key-with-usort)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sortdata = sort2d_bycolumn($data,'ship',SORT_DESC);
function sort2d_bycolumn($array, $column, $method)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
        $narray[$key]  = $row[$column]; 
    }
    array_multisort($narray, $method, $array);
    return $array;
}
```

`sort2d_bycolumn` is the sorting function 
$array is the array you want to sort
$column is the column that array needed to be sorted on
$method value will be either `SORT_ASC` or `SORT_DESC`

Comment: please check the link i have added complete code  http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/am0n-2wm3